# What is difference between .json and .js file which are used while coding three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

.json and .js file are used in three.js. They are one of the object's format. what is difference between them? Do they require different loaders to load the object?

I was following this three.js example: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cars.html. In that example .js file for object and for that BinaryLoader is used. But when I do the same means I had used the .js file for my object with BinaryLoader, it did not worked. It worked for JSONLoader. So I am wondering that how one can recognize .js or .json file and loader for the corresponding object?

Comment: json is the format for javascript (js) objects. It was the designer's choice and he probably had a reason that you should find out by looking into the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> .json and .js file are used in three.js. They are one of the object's format. what is difference between them?

`js` extension marks that content of the file **should be** script following javascript syntax and so is human readable.

`json` extension marks that content of the file **should be** tree structure following javascript object syntax (javascript object has nothing to do with 3d objects) and so is human readable. Also this structure is valid for .js extension, in other words any valid json file is also valid js file.

Three js loaders are from the big part file parsers. These loaders does not care about file extension at all. It is ignored. Only important thing for the parser is content of the file.

> Do they require different loaders to load the object?

As I know, three.js is able to load multiple kinds of structures. Each kind has each own loader (and loader contain one or more parsers).

The most basic one is JSONLoader. It requires file with specific json structure (data about materials, normals, positions, texture coordinates and more or less, not everything is compulsory).

The example you provided uses BinaryLoader. This binary loader requires two files (as I understand). First file contains json structure with materials and location of other file (so json parser is used to parse this file). Second file contains buffers (data about normals, positions, texture coord...) and is binary file. I have no idea what exact binary structure is used here. You see this is kind of hybrid and if you provide buffer data in json structure, it wont be able to read it.

Last loader I have heard of is fbxloader, which can read results created in blender for example. But Im not sure if this one is working.

> In that example .js file for object and for that BinaryLoader is used. But when I do the same means I had used the .js file for my object with BinaryLoader, it did not worked.

I hope this is clear now. BinaryLoader expects two files with json and binary structures. It ignores file name including extension. If you create two files named blablabla.wtf and blabla.omg, but with correct structures inside, it will work. I guess you had one file with correct json structure. This will work with JSONLoader only.

**More about file loaders**

There are 3 aspects we can talk about. Parsing speed, file size and maintainability. 
Parsing speed is more important if you want to download more and more data on the run. 
File size is more important if current size is going to break some limit (that shouldnt or cannot be breaked). 
Maintainability is more important if you need to change the file content a lot.

Binary formats are better for file size and parsing speed. But major browsers use gzip/bzip compression which makes json files almost same size as binary. Maintainability should always be the most important aspect. Json structures are very easy to maintain and debug. fbx or other binary formats are better for big and robust projects with lot of assets.

**EDIT:**

Im afraid I will have to explain a little bit more...

Lets talk about entire concept for a while. Lets say we have an empty world and we would like to put two models inside, simple cube and some animal.

There are three basic ways to do that. Generate it procedurally, use external data or hybrid (part is procedural, part is external data).

*Procedural or hybrid might be for example sea with waves.*

Procedural generation is done by some algorithm in the program, while external data must be inserted with some program tool, the loader.

Examine the cube and the animal now. Cube is just simple object made of 6 planes. It can't move, breathe, eat, anything. It just exists. On the other side, animal is much more complicated, it wont just stay in the middle and does not move. All these things will be part of the external data (file or files).

I provided two very different things, but it is important to know even the simplest things are complicated in 3D and can be manipulated different ways. For example what color does that cube has? Does each plane have same color? Is it shiny? Can it reflect?

The main thing is what kind of description can loader accept, read and understand. First you must know everything about the loader and then you can create an object.

This is example what structures can `JSONLoader` accept:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Geometry-format-4
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Material-format-4

For example, if `"metadata"` contains `"type": "Geometry"`, then loader will look for `"indices"`, `"vertices"`, `"normals"` and `"uvs"`. Some parts might be optional, like `"uvs"`. 
Simple cube can be assembled only from vertices, but it is probably not what this particular loader knows and even if your structure does make sence, it might be unknown for the loader.

*Binary loaders are very different, because there are no words in binary code, just 0 and 1. So you need a lot of metadata to specify what exactly is inside. Metadata can be part of the same file or some different file. But it again depends where the loader will look for them.*

> Could you please tell me, what do mean by JSON structure?

Usually I mean the structure readable with specific loader.

> I am guessing that it might be the content that .js file has.

In case of example you provided, yes in this file is json structure:
http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/obj/veyron/VeyronNoUv_bin.js

> .js file content is different when it is used with BinaryLoader as you have mentioned it contains buffers.

Be more precise, it does not contain buffers. It contains keyword `"buffers":` leading us to file "VeyronNoUv_bin.bin", where are data for buffers. 
Also it contains additional important informations related to  "VeyronNoUv_bin.bin" (*how many vertices, normals etc.*). So you could say, .js file content contains metadata for itself and metadata for related binary file.

Data about vertices, normals etc. are later loaded into buffers in the program, this is why they choose keyword *buffers*. More precise identification would be *dataForBuffers*.

> And when it is used with JSONLoader it contains long list of vertices. Am I understanding right?

Exactly! When JSONLoader is used, long list of *vertices etc.* is readed and then loaded into buffers.

Comment: @ Entity Black: thanks a lot for your answer. Could you please tell me, what do mean by JSON structure? I am guessing that it might be the content that .js file has. .js file content is different when it is used with BinaryLoader as you have mentioned it contains buffers. And when it is used with JSONLoader it contains long list of vertices. Am I understanding right?

Comment: @ Entity Black: Thanks a lot for clearing the doubts and giving the knowledge behind it. Now I am enjoying the learning of three.js. Thanks Entity Black.